# How to change the mouse cursor in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, mouse-cursor

I am making an image editing application, but it looks very incomplete without a cursor like they have in Photoshop for the paintbrush. How can I set the icon, and have it change back when I exit the application?

This is the code in my header file (just in case it's needed):

```
@interface test : NSWindow <NSWindowDelegate> {
    IBOutlet id myView;

}

@end
```

myView is an `NSView` (customView) that will display everything.

Comment: I dont have an answer to your question, but just as a comment, I think you should change `IBOutlet id myView` to `IBOutlet NSView myView`. It always helps to be a bit more specific. I'd suggest avoiding id's if you know what your'e working with.

Comment: @kevin9794 `IBOutlet NSView *myView;` (the `*` is very important :))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a handy [`NSCursor`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSCursor_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class for handling cursor appearance.  If one of the built-in cursors doesn't look how you need it to, you can initialize a new `NSCursor` with an `NSImage` and `-set` it to be the active cursor.

Comment: Even better when combined with NSTrackingArea: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTrackingArea_class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1):

If the drawing area is rectangular(NSTracking Areas are always rectangular) :-
Use the mouseEntered,mouse Exited methods of NSTrackingArea to track and change the mouse cursor.The mouse cursor could be changed using NSCursor class.

If the tracking area is not rectangular then make a bigger rectangular tracking area enclosing the whole drawing region and then track the mouseMoved events inside the tracking area to set the cursor appropriately . Refer to apple documentation for more details.