# Set the cursor to a pointing hand over a text view

Tags: nstextview, mouse-cursor, nstrackingarea

Is there a way to set the cursor to a pointing hand over a text view without subclassing NSTextView?

I read a lot about NSTrackingAreas, tested a lot of examples, set different tracking options and implemented different methods, but the cursor still remains an I-Beam. I have read that it is an AppKit automatic feature, so how can I prevent this?

Thank you!

Comment: You could/should do this with NSCursor. Check this [comment][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544757/how-to-change-the-mouse-cursor-in-objective-c/5544862#5544862

Comment: An updated answer for Swift: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50191113/308315

Answer (score 4):

I had to subclass. After a couple of hours to test a lot of methods and options, this finally worked :

```
@implementation ATTextView

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        _trackingArea = [[NSTrackingArea alloc]initWithRect:[self bounds] options: (NSTrackingMouseMoved | NSTrackingActiveInKeyWindow) owner:self userInfo:nil];
        [self addTrackingArea:_trackingArea];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)mouseMoved:(NSEvent *)event
{
    if ([self isEditable]) [[NSCursor IBeamCursor] set];
    else [[NSCursor pointingHandCursor] set];
}

- (void)updateTrackingAreas {
    [super updateTrackingAreas];
    [self removeTrackingArea:_trackingArea];
    _trackingArea = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:[self bounds] options: (NSTrackingMouseMoved | NSTrackingActiveInKeyWindow) owner:self userInfo:nil];
    [self addTrackingArea:_trackingArea];
}
@end
```

Just to find the correct example (Cocoa is 80% doc reading and 20% coding):
[https://developer.apple.com/library/mac … 0i-CH8-SW1](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac%20%E2%80%A6%200i-CH8-SW1)

Answer (score 3):

this worked for me using Swift 3:

```
class HyperlinkTextField : NSTextField {

    override func resetCursorRects() {
        discardCursorRects()
        addCursorRect(self.bounds, cursor: NSCursor.pointingHand())
    }

}
```

Comment: What does the discardCursorRects do?

Comment: Will this work with NSTextView, which is what the question is about?