# How to prevent a NSCursor from change?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsview, nscursor

I have a problem while I try to prevent a cursor from changing.
I try to put an overlay view over entire window, but, if under that overlay exist an `NSTextView`, this will force cursor to change. I want to prevent that, and keep the arrow cursor until my overlay view will be removed.

Overriding the cursorUpdate method does not work:

```
override func cursorUpdate(with event: NSEvent) {
    return
}
```

Thanks!

Even [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32447739/changing-nscursor-for-nsview-above-an-nstextview)  answer does not help. This solution is valid only if the overlay view is smaller than TextView.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If the `NSTextView` is yours, you can get the behaviour you want by subclassing and overriding `mouseMoved:` there. [There are several examples available, if you search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13658424/set-the-cursor-to-a-pointing-hand-over-a-text-view).

If subclassing the text view is not an option, the best thing would be to use an `NSWindow` for your overlay.

- Create the window with the `NSWindowStyleMaskBorderless` style mask.
- Make the window opaque, set the alpha, background color
- Use `addChildWindow:ordered` to position your overlay

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128134/put-a-transparent-nswindow-permanently-on-top-of-another-nswindow) explains it quite well.

Something like this:

```
var rect = NSRect(x: self.window.frame.origin.x, y: self.window.frame.origin.y, width: self.window.contentView.frame.size.width, height: self.window.contentView.frame.size.height)
var overlay = NSWindow.init(contentRect: rect, styleMask: .borderless, backing: .buffered, defer: false)
overlay.backgroundColor = .red
overlay.isOpaque = false
overlay.alphaValue = 0.5
self.window.addChildWindow(overlay, ordered: .above)
```

Now you can add your overlay view as the window's `contentView`. The cursor will not change in response to the views below.

See [also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49614844/233944).