# Cursor Control in Cocoa App

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have seen applications which allow one to change cursor on Mac.

The Changed cursor is applicable on all apps, something like System Cursor.

Is there an API or something that can allow me to change system cursor, probably with a `.cur` file?

I need a way by which user can assign a different cursor and not the cursor which is applicable to my own application.

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544757/how-to-change-the-mouse-cursor-in-objective-c. If so, we can close this one. If not, describe what is different.

Comment: The difference is that in the other question, author is asking for cursor change in his / her own application. However this question needs assistance in changing cursor on a system level, i.e. cursor applicable to all applications and not a single application.

Comment: Yes, but did you look at the referenced `NSTrackingArea`? It includes `ActiveAlways` as one of its options.

Comment: yes activaealways should work, but unfortunately, it is specific to any given view

Comment: tried this way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16287624/how-to-force-the-cursor-to-be-an-arrowcursor-when-it-hovers-a-nsbutton-that-is